# Textbox like gmail login page

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I want a textbox functionality like a gmail login page textbox. Right now I have code like this:

```
<script>
        function inputFocus(i){
                if(i.value===i.defaultValue){ i.value=""; i.style.color="#000"; }
        }
        function inputBlur(i){
                if(i.value===""){ i.value=i.defaultValue; i.style.color="#888"; }
        }
</script>
<body>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" title="First Name" style="color:#888;" 
          value="First Name" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />
   ...
</body>
```

The problem with this code is when I select the tetbox, type "First Name" and if I reselect the textbox the text is clearing. And also gmail login page textbox functionality looks great, until I type a letter it shows the transperent text. But I don't know how to implement it.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what actually you want to do similar to gmail, if you want to delete the "transparent text" once start typing, why not just use placeholder attribute like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/t36xf6cm/)

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick.   @mGouda

Comment: Hey, you received the same answer from many friends here just right after you get it done. I thought to convert my comment to an answer and you accept it and vote it up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete the "transparent text" once start typing, you can use placeholder attribute of input element

This attribute is introduced in HTML5 to handle this scenario without writing any peice of javascript code

Your html code should look like this

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/>
```

This will also work as desired when you delete your text, as it will reset the transparent text back again.

Also, [here is a working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t36xf6cm/)

I also, encourage you to review [new elements and attributes introduced in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp), it will save a your time writing a lot of javascript to handle already built in functionalities

Answer (score 2):

For the "transparent text" you need to use the [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" ... placeholder="Email">
```

Comment: how this differ from my comment sent 5 min ago?

Comment: @mGouda, because it's an answer, not a comment. (Although I won't give +1 due to a reference to http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for a placeholder ??
If so... you can do like this..

```
<input type="text" name="somename" id="someid" value="" placeholder="Email">
```

`Placeholder` is used to display the text in the text box and will disappear as soon as you start typing..